# Windows Azure Pack and SQL Azure Sharding

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-pack

I seem to be having some difficulty finding answers to my question. Does anyone know if Windows Azure Pack for private clouds allows you to utilize a local version of SQL Azure?  I don't see any mention of SQL Azure in the documentation.  Essentially, I want to insure that the sharding capability exists in private cloud...or will I need to roll my own?

I found the following [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/699319/An-Introduction-to-Windows-Azure-Pack-with-Three-U) which attempts to compare the two and suggests that SQL Azure is not present in Azure Pack, however I have not found any suggestion of this on Microsoft's site.

I did however find a tutorial about how to provision Database As A Service Logic for SQL Server on Azure Pack  [Source](http://blogs.technet.com/b/privatecloud/archive/2014/04/18/working-with-the-windows-azure-pack-sql-server-resource-provider-dedicating-a-part-of-the-sql-server-fabric-to-a-specific-tenant.aspx).  But I'm not sure this is fully inclusive.

Lastly I found some scripting for SSIS Database Sharding [Source](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40743).  Any direction would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Azure Pack for on-premises clouds does not include support for Azure SQL DB.   SQL databases can be implemented for an Azure Pack environment by using Azure Virtual Machines and installing Microsoft SQL Server on the VMs.

The SSIS database Sharding component can be used to target Blob Storage, Azure SQL Database, or a self-sharded on-premises collection of databases -- all it requires are connection strings defining connection strings for various shards.